# Download a file from server

Tags: java, servlets, struts

I have a txt file saved on the Server and I need to make it downloadable to Client
I Tried to do like this i don't know its correct or not i found it on some site,it's not working.

```
 String filePath = fName;
    File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // obtains response's output stream
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        System.out.print(""+buffer);
    }

    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();     

    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Error "+e);
    }
```

Comment: In what way isn't it working?  No file?  An error?  At what point does your code fail?

Comment: no file downloading..

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: it shows no error and i check the file, there is data in it.

Comment: If you try to access the file in the action is it working? A text file wouldn't be an octet-stream, it'd be a text file. Where's the file located?